# How can we update the value of a array field/add a field in nested array in mongodb with a custom value

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nested

In the following JSON, I want to add a column in the "questionResponse" array say "isactive" after "question" field and assigne value to it,how can it be done?

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(253),
    "userId" : NumberLong(1220),
    "languageId" : NumberLong(1),
   "questionResponse" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : NumberLong(27),
            "title" : "I do not have access to the support services",
            "description" : "I do not have access to the support services.",
            "question" : "I do not have access to the support services.",
                      "response" : {
                "value" : [ 
                    "2"
                ]
            },
            "responseExtension" : {
                "comments" : "",
                "reviews" : "",
                           }
        }
    ],
    "locationDetails" : {},
       "isActive" : true
}
```

Comment: welcome to SO... let us know what you have tried

Comment: Hi thanks! I actually want to update the value of "_id" column of questionResponse array.But as _id is immutable, I was trying to create a new column, assign the value of _id to the new column and then update the new column's value

Comment: I have tried the following query that creates the new column db.getCollection('a').update(
 {},
 {$set:{"questionResponse.$[].oldid" : NumberLong(0)}},
 { multi:true}
 )
and was trying to use the following query to update the value of the newly created value db.getCollection('a').update(
 {},
 [{$set:{"questionResponse.oldid" : '$questionResponse._id'}}],
 { multi:true}
 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the [positional **`$`** operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) in your update operaion:

```
db.collection.update(
    { "questionResponse._id": 27 }, 
    { "$set": { "questionResponse.$.isActive": true } }
)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks..this part works,can you please suggest a query for updating the value based on value of other collection?